Updating the google sheet records
I need your help with Zapier. I have two Google Sheet files, A and B. I want Zapier to copy all the records of A to B, but first, delete all records in B. In other words, I want all records of B to be like A after the copy process.
Any guess would be appreciated.
I tried to delete all records of B first, but Zapier can't delete all records at once. Instead, it can delete one row, which is not enough for me.
